# Setting .gif to fit every screen in android

Tags: android, size

I've been working on a live wallpaper for android, an I can't figure out how to set it so that it displays correctly on every screen. It uses and animated gif that is drawn to canvas.  But the gif is different on different screens. I've already read about supporting multiple displays, but I can't get it to work, can some one tell me what I need to add to my draw method below, so that it get's the current display size and resolution and applies it as a variable to the canvas?

Pertinent code is here:   https://github.com/tutsplus/Android-GIFWallpaper/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/hathy/gifwallpaper/GIFWallpaperService.java